# Text Widget Show "Instance of 'Future,String'"

Tags: flutter, dart

Heres the code where I saperated the **SALDO** output

```
Future <String> Saldo() async {
  var rawJson =
  await LG();
  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);

  String saldo = map["SALDO"];

  return(saldo);
}
```

and heres where I call the Function

```
Align(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
                   child: Text(
                   "Rp.${Saldo()}",
                     style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            fontSize: 11.sp),
        )),
```

Other then Showing the Saldo String it shows "Instance of 'Future,String'" on the Text Widget Output

Comment: you have to use FutureBuilder in Text , because the Function is Future

Comment: @Fatimaayaa how to use FutureBuilder ?, can you show me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: Saldo(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
             
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(
               "Rp.${snapshot.data}",
                 style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        fontSize: 11.sp);
                }
                return Container();
              })
```