# Future Builder `build function returned null`

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's the error Message

```
To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
```

I manage to use return but still this happened, Here's my code where the error happened

```
  FutureBuilder(
   future: _getdetailRM(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Container();
   }
  }
 )
```

Comment: here is the solution of your own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934537/text-widget-show-instance-of-future-string

Answer (score 1):

```
    FutureBuilder(
       future: _getdetailRM(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container();
       }else{
    return Container();
    
    }
      }

 )
```